# Limit size for multiple bool query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to search infos from elastic search so for that requirment i use a multiple bool query i want to limit each bool query size with different value from the other, that means each bool query have its own limit . so for that i use this code for the global query. can you help me please and thank you in advance.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "from": "date1",
                            "to": "date2"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        { "match": { "name": "bn1" } },
                                        { "match": { "lastname": "l1" } },
                                        { "match": { "old": "30" } }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        { "match": { "name": "n2" } },
                                        { "match": { "lastname": "l2" } },
                                        { "match": { "old": "20" } }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [MultiSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) The multi search API allows to execute several search requests within the same API. The endpoint for it is _msearch.

Example. How to achieve a union of 3 queries.

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/_msearch?pretty=1'  -d '
{}
{"query" : {"text" : {"title" : "some words"}}, "size" : 5}
{}
{"query" : {"text" : {"title" : "some other words"}}, "size" : 5}
{}
{"query" : {"text" : {"title" : "other words"}}, "size" : 5}
'
```

[image]

Comment: Hi i use ur request and i modify it

`
{"query" : {
  "multi_match": {
    "query": "value1",
    "fields": ["A","B","C"]
     
   }}, "size" : 5
}
{}
{"query" : 
 "multi_match": {
    "query": "value2",
    "fields": ["A","B","C"]
     
   }, "size" : 5} `

i post the query with http://1270.0.1:9200/_msearch?pretty=1


but i get this error 

"type": "json_parse_exception",
"reason": "Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for ROOT starting at [Source: [B@219d9dd1; line: 1, column: 0])\n at [Source: [B@219d9dd1; line: 1, column: 5]"

Comment: You can try with basic query first

Comment: same error with this query:


{"query" : {
  "match": {
    "A": "value"
    
   }}, "size" : 5
}


type": "json_parse_exception",
"reason": "Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: [B@49b50f1f; line: 1, column: 1])\n at [Source: [B@49b50f1f; line: 1, column: 26]"
},
"status": 500
}

Comment: YEs i try it , but with query match it dose not works

have u any idea why i get those errors

Comment: can you try it on POSTMAN ?